# Update all keys with particular value in OrderMap using immutableJs

Tags: javascript-objects, immutable.js

I am trying to find the better way to iterate over all keys using immutableJs.
(Basically, I would like to update all the value in the Map at once.)
Tried by changing tdata.setIn([tdata.keySeq(), "comments"], value =>”new Comment”); setIn , UpdateIn - Deep Persistent Change methods in Immutable

```
let data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    isSelected: false,
    isStarred: false,
    comments: “comments”,
    title: “Title1”,
    userName: “uName”
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    isSelected: false,
    isStarred: false,
   comments: “comments”,
       title: “Title1”,
    userName: “uName”
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    isSelected: false,
    isStarred: false,
    comments: “comments”,
    title: “Title1”,
    userName: “uName”
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    isSelected: false,
    isStarred: false,
    comments: “comments”,
    title: “Title1”,
    userName: “uName”
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    isSelected: false,
    isStarred: false,
    comments: “comments”,
    title: “Title1”,
    userName: “uName”
  }
]

let tData = OrderedMap();
   for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   let values = Map(data[i]);
   tData = tData.set(data[i].id, values);

}

tdata.updateIn([“2”, "comments"], value =>”new Comment”);
```

Rather than explicitly specifying key ="2", am looking to update entire Map
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the [`map`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/map) function.

```
const data = fromJS({
  a: {comment: "1"},
  b: { comment: "2"},
  c: {count: "3"}
);
const newData = data.map((key, value) => {
  if (value.get("comment") == "2")
    return value.set("comment", "new comment")
  else
    return value
});
```